# Calculate the symmetric group of the tetrahedron.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I need to calculate the symmetric group of the tetrahedron but I don't know how to deal with this problem. I think that the answer is $S_4$ and  we have $|S_4| = 4! = 24 $ permutations So can you tell me what to do just write all the permutations and it's all?

Comment: Did You read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry)?

Comment: Not the "symmetric group" but "the group of isometries" (of the tetrahedron). The "symmetric group" is the group of **all** permutations...

Comment: thanks for help

Comment: No, the answer is $A_4$.

Comment: are you considering only orientation preserving symmetries or the set of all symmetries of the tetrahedron?

Comment: Is there difference between the third dimension or the higher one?

Comment: In 2 dimensions, you can only rotate an equilateral triangle, giving it the group A3.  However, if you allow 3 dimensional movement, you could flip the triangle, effectively reversing its orientation, thus giving it the group S3.  The same logic applies for a tetrahedron in 3 and 4 dimensions.